# How can I create an array of void pointers through variadic templates?

Tags: c++

I have something like:

```
class A
{
public:
   A(B* b, int* i)
   {
    void* args[] = { (void*)&b, (void*)&i };
   }
};
```

But I need it to be more generic, in the sense that I want to the constructor of `A` to accept any number of variables, of any type.

How do I accomplish this with templates?

Comment: Do you really want pointer to pointer? Because that's what you're getting with `&b`.

Comment: Yes I need pointer to pointer, I would basically need a template version to achieve what's in the example, and maybe to know if that would be safe or not

Comment: If you're going to make it a template, then why throw away the types to use `void*`?

Comment: Your example just store them in an array. Not that the pointer gets out-of-scope at the end of the constructor, so if you're storing the address of the pointers in `args`, you cannot use `args` outside of the constructor (e.g., this should not be a member). To know if what you're doing is safe or not, you'd need to show us what you're doing with `args`, because simply storing the address of the pointers in `args` is safe, but useless unless you actually use `args`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write your constructor this way:

```
class A {
public:
    template <class... Args>
    A(Args*... pargs) {
        void* args[] = { (void*)&pargs... };
    }
};
```

Note that you are storing the address of the pointers, not the pointers themselves, in `args`.

Also I wouldn't use that kind of things unless you have a very good reason to in actual code.

Answer (score 0):

First of all: Dont't do it! For me it looks like a design bug if you need to convert all and everything to void pointers. But ok, the code can be:

```
class A
{
    public:
        template < typename ... T>
            A(T*... parms)
            {
                void* args[] = { (void*)&parms... };
                /// But what should happen with args??? 
            }
};
```

But why we need pointer to pointer withoud having the types anymore... I have no idea!

Comment: I should maybe have been more clear with the intent. This class is a wrapper I need to launch a CUDA kernel [cudaLaunchKernel API](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-runtime-api/group__CUDART__EXECUTION.html#group__CUDART__EXECUTION_1g5064cdf5d8e6741ace56fd8be951783c)